# How to find Max() within Count() subquery. (Beginner level)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, max

I have 3 tables with following columns:

- Customer(id,name,age,city,country)
- Articles read (customer_id,article_id,date)
- Article (id,name,author)

I have (I think) found out the find the number of times per country that an article has been read:

```
SELECT c.country,a.id,SUM(ar.article_id) AS total_reads FROM customer c
JOIN article a ON c.id = a.id 
JOIN article_reads ar ON c.id = ar.customer_id 
GROUP BY c.country,a.id
ORDER BY total_reads desc;
```

Now I want to found out most read article in each country, with outputs country and article name.

Im trying to SELECT MAX() from the earlier COUNT() output, but I seem to only get errors.
And I think I should also use a DISTINCT clause to only get one distinct max result from the most read article.

```
SELECT (DISTINCT c.country),a.id,MAX(ar.article.id) FROM SUM(ar.article_id) AS total_reads 
FROM customer c
JOIN article a ON c.id = a.id 
JOIN article_reads ar ON c.id = ar.customer_id 
GROUP BY c.country,a.id
ORDER BY total_reads desc;
```

I know there is probably 100 things im doing wrong in this query, but I this is as far as Ive gotten.

Not neccessarily looking for the straight answer, but any tips for how I should go about it would be very welcome

Comment: Sort by found COUNT() in DESC order, take only 1st row.

Comment: I wonder if `JOIN article a ON c.id = a.id` is really correct. I think `JOIN article a ON ar.article_id = a.id` would do a better job.

Comment: I think you're right regarding ar.article_id = a.id is probably more correct, although it doesnt change the output in any way. Funnily enough.

I can order by SUM()(Did you mean COUNT?)  in DESC order, and limit to 1, or 5, but that doesnt seem to  give me the distinct countries, will only give me the top 1, or 5 list.
Like:
Sweden 124834 reads
Iceland 119343 reads
Denmark 102937 reads
Sweden 98232 reads
Sweden 89834 reads:

So it seems the distinct is either placed wrong or something is wrong with my syntax

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should not create a table for views.**

I would do this:

Article table with columns (id, name, author, **views**) and add one at each view.

Then there will be no problem with this question :)

Comment: Not sure how you mean mate. The tables are already made, and Im trying not to change INSERT extra columns. Hoped to find a way without manipulating the tables/columns.

If I understood your reply correctly. If not, feel free to provide example/explanation :)

Comment: You right, mate. I think in the future, namely in work, my approach will be the right one. I advise you to read about data normalization. Unfortunately I can't help more. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you find the `article` read by `DISTINCT` `country` then `query` be like:

```
SELECT a.id AS article_id, a.name AS article_name, COUNT(ar.article_id) AS total_reads, c.country
FROM article_reads ar
JOIN article a ON a.id=ar.article_id
JOIN customer c ON c.id=ar.customer_id
GROUP BY c.country ORDER BY total_reads DESC
```

Comment: That looked a lot cleaner than the mess I came up with. I see there were no use for MAX nor DISTINCT here.

Supposedly we were told to use a subquery, but this looks like a better way of syntaxing it